How Can I change the colors of variables in lstlistings?
So I have some code blocks like the followings
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption={Ejecución de prueba}]
altura_lista = altura.tolist()
peso_lista = peso.tolist()
w, b = train(altura_lista, peso_lista, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 10000)
x = 185
y_pred = predict(x,w,b)
print(y_pred)
\end{lstlisting}

And my documents is configurated:
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{
  language=Python,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.0, 0.5, 0.0},
  identifierstyle=\color{orange},    
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  breaklines=true,
  frame=single,
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=
{á}{{\'a}}1
{é}{{\'e}}1
{í}{{\'i}}1
{ó}{{\'o}}1
{ú}{{\'u}}1
{ü}{{\"u}}1
}

As you can see, I am using orange for identifiers but the problem is, not only variables are painted with orange but functions, libraries, etc.

So, how can I have my variables in orange but the libraries in black and the functions in pink (for example, the color does not matter, just being able to change it).
Thanks.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Taking this answer as a starting point, you can define your own style (lstdefinestyle) and add the names of functions you want to be displayed as keywords (morekeywords).
Taking this answer we see that we can define "different levels" of keywords (classoffset), which can have different colors. Note that I used "peso." instead of just "peso", since otherwise "peso_lista" would be colored, too.
Furthermore I completed your code fragments to an MWE.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listingsutf8,xcolor}
\lstdefinestyle{myPython}{
  language=Python,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.0, 0.5, 0.0},
  identifierstyle=\color{orange},    
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  breaklines=true,
  frame=single,
  extendedchars=true,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  morekeywords={train,predict,tolist},
  classoffset=1,
      otherkeywords={peso.,altura.},
      morekeywords={peso.,altura.},
      keywordstyle=\color{red},
  classoffset=0,
  literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1
    {é}{{\'e}}1
    {í}{{\'i}}1
    {ó}{{\'o}}1
    {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=myPython, caption={Ejecución de prueba}]
altura_lista = altura.tolist()
peso_lista = peso.tolist()
w, b = train(altura_lista, peso_lista, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 10000)
x = 185
y_pred = predict(x,w,b)
print(y_pred)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

